# How to add projects_path(@project) in coffeescript script?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

I am try to add projects_path(@project) in following script, but coffeescript  dont see rails helper.

```
 mangoPay.cardRegistration.sendDataWithAjax(
      # URL to capture response
      "http://localhost:8080/finialize",
      # Card data
      cardData,
      # Result Ajax callback
      (data) ->
        $this.replaceWith('<p> Payment okay</p> </br> <%= link_to 'Back to project', projects_path(@project) %> ')
        #doRedirect = -> window.location.href = data['url']
        #setTimeout doRedirect, 2000

      (xhr, status, error) -> 
        alert("Payment error : " + xhr.responseText + " (" + status + " - " + error + ")")

    )
```

How can correct add url link in $this.replaceWith fnction? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: your js will not have any way to access the `@project` first thing if js is written inside the `app/assets/javascript` folder, AFAIK

Comment: ok. than how can i add url link from action to this script?

Comment: url you can write by hand, but the ID of the project you need to grab from the HTML somehow and add it to the url. pretty easy :)

Comment: Arup, how add id? Can you show example

Comment: tough to help you by looking at this much code, you can grab it from HTML by using Jquery.

Comment: i store project_id in action controller, than call this script. I cant undestand how and from where can I grab from html project_id?

Comment: Create a hidden field on your form. Populate that field with your URL. Read that field from CoffeeScript.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the problem use following

1. User format.js to respond with user
2. create corresponding javascript file i.e. for def new , new.js.erb
3. then you can use ruby code inside javascript

**Remember there is no way or might not exists to directly access rails variable in coffee script**